# Zebra ZQ 510 Mobile Printer compatible with Motorola MC32NO (Windows Embedded Compact 7.0)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-ce, zebra-printers

Have problem to get connect with the new purchased Zebra ZQ 510 mobile printer from Motorola MC32N0 via bluetooth by using the following legacy code(referencing InTheHand.Net.Personal dll):

```
using InTheHand.Net;
using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth;
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
using InTheHand.Net.Ports;

BluetoothAddress mac = BluetoothAddress.Parse("B0B44879581D");
BluetoothEndPoint btEndPoint = new BluetoothEndPoint(mac, BluetoothService.SerialPort);
BluetoothClient bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient();
bluetoothClient.Connect(btEndPoint);
```

My workaround is to use BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest() function to pair the printer, but manually assign a Serial Port( either COM5 or COM9) by using BTUI application. Then use following code(referencing Zebra Link OS SDK(ZSDK_API.dll)):

```
using ZSDK_API.Comm;
// Instantiate connection for ZPL Serial port on COM5. 
ZebraPrinterConnection thePrinterConn = new SerialPrinterConnection("COM5");
// Open the connection - physical connection is established here.
thePrinterConn.Open();
```

to connect to it to print.

have two questions to ask:
1. Would like to know whether Zebra ZQ 510 Mobile Printer with Smart Bluetooth compatible  with Motorola MC32NO (Running on Windows Embedded Compact 7.0)? 
2. Is there a way to create virtual COM Port programmatically in Windows CE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find out a solution.   Downloaded **Motorola EMDK for .NET v2.9**, and referenced **Symbol.WPAN.dll**. by using following code, managed to connect to the **Zebra ZQ510 printer**, and printed out label as expected.  Don't forget to copy **BTInterface.dll** from EMDK to the program folder.

```
        using Symbol.WPAN.Bluetooth;
        Bluetooth m_Bluetooth = new Bluetooth();
        m_Bluetooth.Enable();
        RemoteDevice rd = new RemoteDevice("", currentBTPrinterMacAdd, "");
        rd.LocalComPort = LocalComPortForZebraPrinterZQ510;
        m_Bluetooth.RemoteDevices.Add(rd);

        if (!rd.IsPaired)
            rd.Pair();

        rd.OpenPort();
        rd.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(template));

        rd.ClosePort();
        rd.UnPair();

        m_Bluetooth.Disable();
        m_Bluetooth.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same issue on the QLN320 without Zebra link. In the hand would pair but if you tried to use a local port it would error.

Here is the same example only in VB 2008. It works fine but is a little slow connecting at times.

```
Imports Symbol.WPAN
Imports Symbol.WPAN.Bluetooth
Imports System.Text



Dim printline As String = ""
printline = printline & "! 0 200 200 631 1" & vbCrLf 
printline = printline & "PW 576" & vbCrLf
printline = printline & "TONE 0" & vbCrLf
printline = printline & "SPEED 4" & vbCrLf
printline = printline & "ON-FEED IGNORE" & vbCrLf
printline = printline & "NO-PACE" & vbCrLf
printline = printline & "GAP-SENSE" & vbCrLf
printline = printline & "BT 7 0 3" & vbCrLf
printline = printline & "B 128 2 30 458 69 62 02029990324041000014" & vbCrLf 
printline = printline & "PRINT" & vbCrLf

Dim m_Bluetooth As New Bluetooth
m_Bluetooth.Enable()
m_Bluetooth.RemoteDevices.DeleteAll()
Dim rd As New RemoteDevice("Printer35", "", "") 
rd.LocalComPort = 5
m_Bluetooth.RemoteDevices.Add(rd)

Try

    If Not (rd.IsPaired) Then
        rd.Pair("0035")
    End If

    rd.OpenPort()

    Dim ByteArray As Byte() = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(printline & vbCrLf)

    rd.Write(ByteArray)

    rd.ClosePort()

    rd.UnPair()
    m_Bluetooth.RemoteDevices.DeleteAll()

Catch ex As Exception

    MessageBox.Show("Error  - " & ex.Message.ToString)

End Try

m_Bluetooth.Disable()
m_Bluetooth.Dispose()
```